# JavaScript Object.create in old IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is there a way to make this code backwards compatible with IE6/7/8?

```
function Foo() {
    ...
}

function Bar() {
    ...
}

Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
```

The main problem is `Object.create` errors, then crashes the browser.

So is there a function I can drop in to emulate the behavior of `Object.create` for old IE. Or how should I re-code the above to work around it?

Comment: [There is a polyfill in the MDN documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: @Pointy make an answer if you want the rep.

Comment: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate? http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointy's comment as an answer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            throw new Error('Object.create implementation only accepts the first parameter.');
        }
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

This polyfill covers the main use case which is creating a new object for which the prototype has been chosen but doesn't take the second argument into account.